# Break out of a case (in a switch) from within a condition

Tags: switch-statement

Before I came to ask this question, I tried with PHP and it works but I wonder if it is considered standard.

So here's the situation, I have a huge switch/case statement with each case treating a specific HTTP request based on the request header. In one case I want to update rows in a mysql table if a variable is true and delete rows if it's false so I wondered if I could do something like this :

```
<?php
switch ($request) {
    case 'stuff':
        stuff();
        break;
    case 'thatThing':
        if (!$theVar) {
            deleteTheRows();
            // Break out of the switch statement so that the rest of this case is ignored
            break;
        }
        updateTheRows();
        break;
    default:
        otherStuff();
        break;
}
?>
```

The idea is to have `break;` act like a `return` would in a function letting me treat all the exceptional cases before going on with the normal situation's code without nesting it in an additional indentation depth

Answer (score 0):

```
In one case I want to update rows in a mysql table if a variable is true
and delete rows if it's false
```

An else cause is just as effective...

```
<?php
switch ($request) {
    case 'stuff':
        stuff();
        break;
    case 'thatThing':
        if (!$theVar) {
            deleteTheRows();
        } else {
            updateTheRows();
        }
        break;
    default:
        otherStuff();
        break;
}
?>
```